# Activity of my android project is skipping

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a simple android project. but, the problem is 2nd activity among all 3 of it's activities is skipping. logcat displays few warnings.

```
"Skipped 108 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
```

My 2nd activity-

```
EditText et1,et2,et3,et4;
Button btn;
int i,counter;
double theory_credit,theory_gp,lab_credit,lab_gp,total_credit,total_gp,cgpa;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);

    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    et4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    String value=getIntent().getStringExtra("Input");
    counter=Integer.parseInt(value);
    theory_credit=theory_gp=lab_credit=lab_gp=total_credit=total_gp=cgpa=0.0;

    for(i=1;i<=counter;i++){


        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String inp;

                inp=et1.getText().toString();
                theory_credit=Double.parseDouble(inp);
                et1.setText("");
                inp=et2.getText().toString();
                theory_gp=Double.parseDouble(inp);
                et2.setText("");
                inp=et3.getText().toString();
                lab_credit=Double.parseDouble(inp);
                et3.setText("");
                inp=et4.getText().toString();
                lab_gp=Double.parseDouble(inp);
                et4.setText("");

                if(theory_gp>0.0 && theory_credit>0.0){
                    total_credit+=theory_credit;
                    total_gp+=(theory_gp*theory_credit);
                }

                if(lab_gp>0.0 && lab_credit>0.0){
                    total_credit+=lab_credit;
                    total_gp+=(lab_gp*lab_credit);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if(total_credit>0.0){
        cgpa=total_gp/total_credit;
    }

    Intent intent=new Intent(AnotherActivity.this, FinalActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Result", cgpa);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

how can i fix this ?
My 1st and 3rd activities are working well.

Comment: Did you test this on an emulator or a real device? Most of the times, this error is due to slow emulators.

Comment: Are you seeing this when running app on emulator or on a real device?

Comment: i tried both, on emulator and real device. but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add two layouts in a single java class. Each layout is associated with only a single class. Hence, in your code you have written `setContentView(R.id.yourLayout)` twice, which is not needed. And moreover, in a single UI thread you cannot put two layouts, which may also be one reason for your crash.

Comment: if i make comment the first        
        "setContentView(R.id.yourLayout)"

outside the loop then the program crashes and if i put that statement then it simply skip the 2nd activity.

Comment: If you have to move to another activity use INTENTS, the approach you are using is not appropriate. And also set the content view just after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) function, which will definitely solve your problem

Comment: actually i'm taking 4 inputs using editText in every iteration of the loop.
thus i need to set blank field for input, so i put that statement       

      "setContentView(R.id.yourLayout)".

after taking the final input i'm sending the calculated value to the next activity.

Comment: for setting the blank fields, remove the text in the editText by using `e1.setText("");` or `editText.getText().clear();` no need of setting the views again.

Comment: tried both, but same result. the 2nd activity is skipping.

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);` remove this inside the loop.

Comment: i removed that and then put  "et1.setText("");"

Comment: add `et1.setText("")` just before every `theory_credit=Double.parseDouble(inp);` line, for respective editText, and then try

Comment: Still skipping. by the way, as the discussion is getting extended i think we should move to the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);` from inside your for loop. You've already set your view above. Did you put it inside there for any reason?

Comment: same result even after removing that statement.

Comment: because the last activity should start after terminating the loop.